# IMG Modal only working on first image

Tags: html, css

Wondering if I can get some help.

I'm currently practicing html/css and I'm working on my first modal page.

http://digitalarts.lmu.edu/jvysel1/portfolio.html

Right now, I'm having issues with having the modal work on every image. For some reason it's only working on the first.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: You should provide the code you have in your website

Comment: You need to create a reproducible example of your code and post it in the question itself. Check out this post on Meta: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

You assigned an id = "myImg" to all images. That's a mistake, id's are for indicating a singular element in html. You should use a class "myImg" and assign that class to all images.

```
id = singular element

class = multiple elements
```

Hope this helps!